# FB like chathead gone after app closed

Tags: android

I was trying to show a floating window which will be top of any app even if my app is close.
I followed this [link](https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead)
Problem is that when I close my app by pressing home button and close all app then the floating window disappear.

But I want that even my app is close in whatever way I want to show the floating window. It will be close only when a close button is pressed which will be attached to that floating window.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Based on the Library you used, the `chatHead` is being removed in `onDestroy`. Originally, views drawn via `windowManager` will not be removed unless you explicitly told it to do so.

If you want your chatHead to stay, remove the code where the view is being removed in `ChatHeadService - onDestroy`.

Comment: But if i drag the chatHead to the remove view ,the service should be destroyed and the chatHeadView has to be removed.

Comment: When i close my app by pressing home button ,ondestroy of the service is not called.

Comment: *I want that even my app is close in whatever way I want to* not possible. If user force stops your app, you can't do anything anymore